# Is punch name of a person

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of the following sentence

> Punch is distinguished from its hunchback.

Is Punch name of a person?

Comment: Do you have some more context? It sounds like it might be an animal's name, i.e. this animal is identifiable from the others _by_ its hunched back.

Comment: Could you please provide more context? It's very hard to tell what 'Punch' is referring to in this sentence. It's likely not a person's name because of the pronoun 'its' later in the sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Punch" most likely is Mr Punch from [Punch and Judy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punch_and_Judy), and the sentence seems to come from [here](https://targetstudy.com/languages/english/preposition-exercise-7.html) and is misquoted. The missing preposition should probably be "by":

> Punch is distinguished **by** his hunchback.

It means that Punch's back, which is a [hunchback](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyphosis) (suffering from kyphosis) is a distinguishing characteristic of Punch, something which makes him recognizable.

Comment: Well done, TypeIA.